# Search dir using wildcard string, return filename, and loop

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm having some problems, and looking for some help.  I'm trying to create a photo gallery in javascript, that will be able to 'update' it's self automatically.  I need to be able to search a directory, and grab a file with a specific prefix.

I need to output the followng HTML code:

```
<li><a href="images/resize_FILENAME.ext"><img src="images/thumb_FILENAME.ext"></a></li>
```

The 'resize_' and 'thumb_' use a timestamp to identify, so they have the same ending, just a different prefix.

So, for example, if I search the directory for an image with a prefix of 'resize_', I need to insert that into the a tag, and then remove the '_resize' prefix, and add the '_thumb' prefix for the img tag.  I then need to be able to do that for each image in the directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oh, I should add:

I'm assuming php would be easiest for this, but if an alternative exists that would work too.  I'm also using jQuery if javascript would be better.

Answer (score 1):

After some reading about the `glob()` function, I was able to figure it out pretty easily.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
foreach (glob("upload_pic/thumbnail_*.*") as $thumb) {
    $resize = preg_replace("/thumbnail_/", "resize_", $thumb);
    echo "<li><a href='$resize'><img src='$thumb'></a></li>";
}
?>
```

So, basically, the `glob()` function searches my `upload_pic` directory for any file with the `thumbnail_` prefix.  I then create run the `preg_replace()` function to replace the `$thumb` variable's `thumbnail_` with `resize_`, and make that the `$resize` variable.  Then just `echo` the proper HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

To search a directory using wildcard string, `glob()` function can be used.

But how to learn AJAX and use `glob()` results from the PHP script on the client side, is probably another question.